# How to Install and use jquery-ui in laravel mix using npm

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, laravel-mix

I'm confused about the usage of jquery-ui, I have already followed some instructions regarding ***"how to install jquery-ui using npm for laravel mix"***, however I still get an error and I don't know if I have made a mistake with the installation, I'm hoping I can receive some help with my problem.

To install jQuery, I used the following `npm` command:

```
npm install jquery-ui --save-dev
```

And for the imports to use jQuery (I'm using them in my_file.js and not in app.js):

```
import $ from "jquery";
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

import "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js";
import "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider.js";
```

As for my code, I want to make a sliding effect when my button is clicked:

```
$("#right-arrow").on("click", function() {
  cardLength.slice(0, oddEven).toggle('slide', {
      direction: 'left'
  }, 1000);
});
```

I then run the command:

```
npm run dev
```

Upon doing so, I get this error in the console:

```
VM1005 collection.js:11247 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
at init.run (VM1005 collection.js:11247)
at tick (VM1005 collection.js:11631)
at Function.jQuery.fx.tick (VM1005 collection.js:11973)
at schedule (VM1005 collection.js:11350)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make use of easing effects from jQuery, you need to import a seperate library called jQuery Easing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.easing

Comment: how can I import? import in my_file.js?

Comment: First install it with `npm install jquery-easing`, then import it in using an `import` statement as normal, the same way you have imported jQuery already.

Comment: oh ok I will install the libraries, thanks for your advice

Comment: I already import this `import "jquery.easing/jquery.easing.js"` to my_file.js, but I still got an error

Comment: Ensure that the install location is the same as the path you are trying to import it from, it sounds like you are not importing it from the correct place of where it is relative to your file.

Comment: oh okay, I just make a little fault, and I already done with my problem, thanks one more time